# James Bond film in which he plays a computer game

Tags: identify-this-movie, james-bond

There's one James Bond film where he is playing a game against the bad guy. It looks like a 1v1 game of Battleships or something.

Anyone know which one it is?

Comment: Thanks! I uploaded that YouTube video of the "**Domination**" video/computer game which uses the vocals of the **EMS Vocoder-System 3000**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In [Never Say Never Again](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086006/), (1983), James Bond plays "Domination" against Maximilian Largo.

Comment: Lucky you - I was looking through the Dalton/Brosnan episodes since I thought it happened later.

Comment: thanks, this must be the only Bond film I haven't seen about a million times

Comment: @cantsay In fact it isn't counted to the main franchise, as it is more or less a remake of *Thunderball* (or rather another adaptation of the base novel, to which the filming rights were still available, albeit in a legally complicated way) and wasn't produced by *Eon*.